# C# replace all occurrences of a character with just a character

Tags: c#, string, replace

Let's say I have this string, `"%%%%%ABC"`, I would like to replace all the `"%"` with just one `"%"`, so it should be `"%ABC"`.

If its `"%%%A%%B%%C%%"`, it should be `"%A%B%C%"`

How should I do this?

Comment: And is it just for `%` or do you also have `"###A##B#C"` ?

Comment: So far I'm only dealing with "%". The issue I'm facing is that, I have a program where users can filter values using SQL filter. My program freezes if they enter stuff like "%%%%%%%%ABC" instead of "%ABC", which of course I will convert "%" to ".*" to be regex compliant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a solution with `Regex.Replace` method:

```
private static string TruncatePercents(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"%+", "%");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This'll sort it:

```
    string ProcessText(string s)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(s, @"%+", "%");
    }
```

**Edit** Got beaten to the punch, so to make mine slightly different and to offer scope for varying delimeters:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = ProcessText(textBox1.Text, "%", "#");
    }

    string ProcessText(string s, string delim, string replaceWith)
    {
       return Regex.Replace(s, @""+ delim + "+", replaceWith);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to replace one or more non-word characters with the single same non-word character.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(\W)+", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression.

```
        string strTest = "%%%A%%B%%C%%";
        string strPattern = "%+";
        RegexOptions opt = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        var reg = new Regex(strPattern, opt);
        var strReplaceResult = reg.Replace(strTest, "%");
```

result will be "%A%B%C%"