# Regex to remove multiple consecutive commas and replace with single comma

Tags: c#, regex

Given the input string "Test,,test,,,test,test"

and using the following C# snippet I would have expected the duplicate commas to be replaced by a single comma and results in...

"Test,test,test,test"

```
private static string TruncateCommas(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @",+", ",");
}
```

Code was pinched from this answer...
[C# replace all occurrences of a character with just a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544968/c-sharp-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-with-just-a-character)

But what I am seeing is "Test,,test,,,test,test" as the output from this function.

Do I need to escape the comma in the regex? Or should this regex be working.

Comment: your code works as expected

Comment: Wild guess: You're not looking at the return value from that method.

Comment: Why not direct pattern `@",{2,}"`: *two or more* commas...

Comment: @itsme86: `@",{2,}"` is *more readable* and (at least potentially) more effcient: we don't touch *single* commas

Comment: "But what I am seeing is.." please post the way that you test the function. The error is there

Comment: I had a spaces between the commas. I've ammended my Regex and now all is happy. Regex.Replace(concatenatedString, @"(,\s)+", @"$1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to escape the comma in the regex?

No.

> Or should this regex be working.

Yes.

Please construct your test the following way:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = "Test,,test,,,test,test";

    string result = TruncateCommas(s);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output

> `Test,test,test,test`

Comment: Thankyou for making me think about this correctly. It was indeed the input. string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}", ...). There was a space in between the commas on my input!

Comment: @Nattrass your welcome, glad to hear that you solved your problem. Good fortune